# How to fix the borders of a node to the contents in it

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a BorderPane in JavaFx and I want the center's size to be fixed to the size of its children

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<3; j++) {
                Label label = new Label("");
                label.setMinHeight(70); label.setMinWidth(70);
                label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(226, 155, 100);");
                gridPane.add(label, i, j);
            }
        }
        gridPane.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 10px; -fx-border-color: #663820;");

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(gridPane);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

After running this code if you resize the application, the border follows the edge while the content in it has expanded to its max size.

[image: Output After running and resizing the application]

How do I attach the border to the contents. Ideally I want the extra space generated on resizing to go to the outer nodes(top left bottom right) and the center to remain packed with its contents. Thus the center expands till all its children reach Max specified size and then stop.
[image]

Comment: You have to specify how _exactly_ your layout should behave, f.i. what should be in the empty space (it's not a border, just an aera not covered by the center nor any of other borderPane child)? Depending on that spec there are several options, f.i. constraint the set the borderPane's max to its pref and disallow window resizing.

Comment: Don't set the size of the `Scene`. Change this line: `primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane, 300, 275));` to this line: `primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane));`

Comment: @Abra I did that, but that did not fix the problem, only thing it did is make the application original size smaller.

Comment: @kleopatra The empty space should go to the exterior nodes (top, left, bottom right), while the center should remain packed... How to achieve this?

Comment: then BorderPane is the wrong layout, don't use it - please read its the api doc to understand how it resizes its children and distributes space

Comment: what do you suggest instead?

Comment: did you read the api doc? write your own .. suspect, though, that you still didn't _exactly_ specify your space distribution/resize requirements (and might still mis-understand the notion of _border_) - show an example of what should be in the the other regions (like bottom etc). Setting alignment might be all you need ..

Comment: @Abra added a diagram trying to explain how the final GUI should look

Comment: repeating: that's not supported by BorderPane - if you really want it, write your own (it's not that difficult, start from BorderPane code and change such that excess space goes into the boundary children vs. center

Comment: Use a `GridPane`, not a `BorderPane`, and allocate the extra space using combinations of `RowConstraints`, `ColumnConstraints`, and/or `setHgrow()` and `setVgrow()`.